# Определение методов класса с одинаковой сигнатурой

Tags: c#, .net, интерфейс

У меня имеется класс, определенный ниже

```
class SomeType
    : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() { Console.WriteLine("Dispose class"); }
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { Console.WriteLine("Dispose interface"); }
}
```

**Почему этот код компилируется?** Разве у нас фактически не объявлено два одинаковых метода с одинаковой сигнатурой?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Второй метод является [явной реализацией интерфейса](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation), так что все нормально. Он будет вызван только при явном приведении типа `SomeType` к `IDisposable`, тогда как первый метод будет вызываться при работе напрямую с `SomeType`.